# Build this LEFT() "SQL" in MongoDB Query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Have an `BsonDocument` collection with *PhoneNumber* in the "1234567890" format. This SQL gets all the PhoneNumbers with the Area Codes between 300 and 399;

```
WHERE (LEFT(PhoneNumber,3) BETWEEN '300' AND '399')
```

How would I do this in MongoDB? I would like to use the `MongoDB.Driver.Builders` if possible.

Comment: LEFT is substringing for the first three characters of the string.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use that? Like this?
    var gte = Query.GTE("LEFT(PhoneNumber,3)", "300");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want phone number that's starts from number '3' you can just use smart decision of *@mstearn*, here just  c# realization:

```
var query = Query.EQ("PhoneNumber", new BsonRegularExpression("^3"));
```

But lets say if you need query first 3 numbers in range 345 -- 369 to make it work (without slow operators: `$where`, `$regex`) you can create additional field and store there first 3 numbers (area code) of phone. And then use query proposed by *@yi*_H , here again c# driver realization:

```
var query = Query.GTE("PhoneAreaCode", 345).LTE(369);
```

Don't care about *extra* field in mongodb -- it's common practice. Extra fields usual working faster than any calculation during querying.

Comment: Thanks for the verbose answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
{'PhoneNumber': {'$gte': '300', '$lt': '400'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{'PhoneNumber': /^3/ } or {'PhoneNumber': {'$regex': '^3'}}
```