# Best Way to truncate text for preview before uploading to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I already know how to achieve this by doing it with css ellipsis.

But if I query all the text content from a db and simply 'mask' it with css, I find that it is inefficient and creates unnecessarily large bandwidth than it has to.

Is there a common practice/pattern to truncate a text content and save it with the actual content in a db?

I am currently using css ellipsis method but like I mentioned above, It seems unnecessary.

Comment: Simply truncating the text server-side, before you return the page is sufficient. The bandwidth to the client is much more important than database-to-server.

Comment: If they change the query to only return what they need then they save bandwidth between their own servers and get the requests to clients finished faster.

Comment: @JosephEvans: If the database servers are remote from the web servers, but that is often not the case. Just advising that the server-client is usually more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can mimic the SQL LEFT() method for MongoDB like the example given here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686555/4488318 It should allow you to grab the first however many characters for your preview text.

Comment: would this be better than truncating before upload then adding a preview field?

Comment: It keeps your data in one place and reduces redundancy. It also keeps your text from possibly getting out of sync if you update one but not the other. The first answer in the linked thread mentions that using a separate field would be better for performance.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!